# Why reference a pointer to a struct array explicitly instead of just via pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Up until now I have always accessed a pointer to a struct array thus:

```
struct blah *ptr; ptr[10].member = 1;
```

I recently became aware of another way:

```
struct blah (*array_ptr)[]; (*array_ptr)[10].member = 1;
```

The only restriction I've found, is it prohibits `array->member` access forcing [] usage.

**Question**: Are there any pros/cons to the explicit [] method to either a) humans or b) compilers between either method?

For humans, I guess it makes it explicit that the pointer is to an array, as opposed to the  'normal' use where it is ambiguous.

Comment: The second is a pointer to an array, not an array of pointers.  There are use cases for this, too, but they are less common than for the other two forms.

Comment: `ptr` points to the first element of an array of `struct blah`, while `array_ptr` points to the array itself. The two pointees have the same address, only the type is different. The compiler will generate identical machine code for both.

Comment: @Zakk No, it is not.

Comment: No, @Zakk, it is not.

Comment: @Zakk: For one thing, `array_ptr + 1` will compile with your declaration but not with OP's.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply either was an array of pointers @JohnBollinger :-)

Comment: No, @Ian, I'm sure you didn't.  But another comment, now deleted, did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Up until now I have always accessed a pointer to a struct array thus:
>
> ```
> struct blah *ptr; ptr[10].member = 1;
> ```

That demonstrates a pointer to a struct (that happens to be an element of an array of at least 11 such structs), ***not*** a pointer to an array of structs.  It is, however, the pointer type to which an array of `struct blah` would decay.

> I recently became aware of another way:
>
> ```
> struct blah (*array_ptr)[]; (*array_ptr)[10].member = 1;
> ```

*That* is a pointer to an array of [an unspecified number of] structs.

The addresses to which these two pointers point may be the same, but the pointers have different types.

> The only restriction I've found, is it prohibits `array->member`
> access forcing [] usage.

You can use either form to access `struct blah` objects indirectly.  Yes, the syntax for doing so is different between the two cases, on account of the pointer types being different.

> Question: Are there any pros/cons to the explicit [] method to either
> a) humans or b) compilers between either method?

I daresay most people find the structure pointer variation easier to read and understand than the array pointer version.  It ought to make no difference at all to a compiler, because if `array_ptr` points to the array whose first element is `*ptr`, and that array indeed does have at least 11 elements, then the two example assignments are 100% equivalent.

> For humans, I guess it makes it explicit that the pointer is to an
> array, as opposed to the 'normal' use where it is ambiguous.

A pointer can *always* be considered to point to an array, though that may be an array of length 1.  There is no particular usefulness in trying to draw a distinction, at least not by varying the type of the pointer.  It gets more interesting and more useful when you have pointers to arrays with known length (example: `struct blah (*array11_ptr)[11];`), but I don't see many use cases for your unspecified-length version.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I was trying the (*)[] version to see if I could coax gcc's -fanalyzer into not issuing false-positives but it didn't do anything (which could also mean my code is still buggy, of course, but as it's a toy-operating system I'm not convinced gcc is quite up to the analysis yet.)